# Regex - Match alpha characters that don't match a subset of alpha characters (C#)

Tags: c#, regex

Say I have a collection of strings "123AB", "456CDEF", "789G", "012-HI".  How do I find all the strings that are number(1 or more) followed by alpha(1 or more) with no special characters, where the alpha characters are not *AB*?

To clarify, the regex applied to the previous collection should yield "456CDEF" and "789G".  "123AB" is ignored because the alpha value is *AB* and "012-HI" is ignored because it contains a non-alpha.  The regex for what I'm looking for, minus the special *AB* rule, is `^[0-9]+[A-Z]+$`.  Case is irrelevent.  I've tried a few variations of the `[^ ]` rule with no success, since all the patterns I came up with allowed special characters.

To generalize, how can I match a set of alpha values that don't match a certain subset of alpha values, using a single regex pattern?

**Note**: "123ABC" should be accepted as well.  Only strings with *AB* exactly should be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a lookahead assertion: `^[0-9]+(?!AB$)[A-Z]+$`

Comment: Short, sweet, and easily scalable when AB becomes AB, CD, and EF!

Answer (score 0):

Without look-ahead:

> ^[0-9]+([B-Z]|A[AC-Z])[A-Z]*$

**Edit:**
Withdrawn, because this won't match something like `123A`.  But I'll leave the answer visible as an example of what won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`^\d+(?:a(?:b[a-z]+|[^b][a-z]*)?|[^a][a-z]*)$`
start of string, then 1 or more digit, then either (A) a followed by b followed by more letters, or (B) a followed by any letter other than b and optionally any letter after that, or (C) any letter other than a followed by any letter, then end of string